# How to append events or functions using jquery, from Chrome Dev Tools Console to the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not a front-end developer, then I'm new with jquery, now when I develop/design anything
I use a lot the Console of Chrome Developer Tools to test my queries, that's so usefull.

But today I faced an Issue, I need to put a click event to one div, I put the function on the View(MVC), then launch the app, pass the login, click here, click there.
And when the moment of test is come, the event didn't worked.

Then would be fine if with jquery I could append a new click event to the div, from the Console of Chrome Dev Tools rather than change the view-compile-execute, etc.

How I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can run code in the console, however if you want to add that code to your page, you must do that directly in the file for that page, it can't be done from the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I really got what you meant. But I think what you mean is how to trigger a click event on a particular div.

If that is it, you can use `$("div#id").click();` (It is a shortcut for `$("div#id").trigger("click")` )

You can run this on the console, of course